# How to install Android SDK on windows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have recently installed Android Studio. In the initialization of the app, it said "Android SDK is missing" so I proceeded to download the command line only version from https://developer.android.com/studio.

I tried running the android.bat file but it did not open, I am using JDK 12.0.1 and I have also tried adding `java\bin` to the PATH but it still doesn't work. It simply opens a cmd window and then closes it.

Comment: Please download Android SDK for windows and set path in Android studio.

Comment: How did you install Android Studio because either it asks you to tick the SDK you want to download during install or installs the latest automatically, I don't quite remember which one is it. Try installing again and check if it asks you to download SDK during install. I'm just saying it should be there after installing Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the command line tools at the [downloads page](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#command-tools) under the "Command line tools only" section.

The installer version for windows doesn't seem to be available any longer, this is the link for version 24.4.1:

Windows installer: [https://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe]